# Is there alternative functions in PySpark as countAll,countAllDistinct in Azure data Flow

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have count-->counts null exclusive
countAll---> counts null inclusive
Similarly countDistinct ,countAllDistinct in Azure Data Flow Aggregation transformation.

But in pySpark,there are only count() and countDistinct().So how to achieve countAll() and CountAllDistict() in PySpark.

Comment: please add code you are using to count rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know there is no Built-in functions for `CountAll` and `CountDistinctAll` to work around it you can follow below:

To count all rows in a PySpark DataFrame, including null values, you can use the `count()` function directly without using the `when()` function.

**If you have dataframe in pyspark**:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, col, sum, countDistinct, when
#count all rows excluding null
df.select(count("column name")).show()
#count all rows including null
df.select(sum(when(col("column name").isNull() | col("column name").isNotNull(), 1).otherwise(0))).show()

  
#count all distinct rows excluding null
df.select(countDistinct("column name")).show()
#count all distinct rows including null
df.select("column name").distinct().count()
```

**Execution and OUTPUT:**
[image]

**If you have dataframe in pyspark**:

```sql
#count all rows including null
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM (Select value from sampleView);

#count all distinct rows including null
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS distinct_total_count FROM (Select  distinct value from sampleView);
```

**Execution and OUTPUT:**

[image]